# Angular 5 : Sending an array of HTTP request that need to be executed in sequential order

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am trying to send an array of HTTP requests which need to be executed in sequential order, but i have no clue on how to do that. Below are details of my application.

Application Entities :

- Location - an entity which can has the following attributes:`FanZone fanZone`, `List<LocationAdministrator> locationAdmins`
- FanZone - an entity which has the following attributes: `List<FanZoneAdministrator> fanZoneAdmins`

Idea:

- By filling the form on the picture below, and clicking "NEXT" button, i am saving an Location object in one of my Angular services, because i dont want to POST it until the application user completes filling up administrator information ( form for filling in admin information is presented to the user after clicking on "NEXT" button ).

[image]

- After application user successfully fills in the Location Information form presented on picture above, he has to fill in the information on Location Administrators and Fan Zone Administrators. The form is presented in the picture below.

[image]

- When application user successfully fills in administrator forms presented in the picture above, I would like to register Location entity ( send POST request ), and AFTER that same Location entity has been posted to the Database, i want to send an array of HTTP POST requests in order to register list of `LocationAdministrator` and list of `FanZoneAdministrator` entities.

Angular code:

```
next() {

    this.locationService.registerLocation(this.location).subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
        console.log('Successfully registered Location!');
        console.log(response.json());
      },
      (error: Response) => {
        console.log('Error occured while trying to register new Location');
      }
    );

    var fanZoneAdmin: User;

    this.registerFanZoneAdminForm.get('fanZoneAdminArray').value.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
      fanZoneAdmin = new User(element.username,element.password,element.email,element.firstName,element.lastName,element.city,element.phoneNumber, null,null,null,null, null,this.location.fanZone,null,new Role("FZA"),null);

      this.usersService.registerFanZoneAdmin(fanZoneAdmin).subscribe(
        (response: Response) => {
          console.log('Successfully registered Fan Zone Administrator!');
          console.log(response.json());

        },
        (error: Response) => {
          console.log('Error occured while trying to register new Fan Zone Administrator');
        }
      );
    });

    console.log('Submitting Location Administrator!')
    var locationAdmin: Location;

    this.registerLocationAdminForm.get('locationAdminArray').value.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
      locationAdmin = new User(element.username,element.password,element.email,element.firstName,element.lastName,element.city,element.phoneNumber,  null, null,null, null, null,null,this.location, new Role("LA"),null);

      this.usersService.registerLocationAdmin(locationAdmin).subscribe(
        (response: Response) => {
          console.log('Successfully registered Fan Zone Administrator!');
          console.log(response.json());
        },
        (error: Response) => {
          console.log('Error occured while trying to register new Fan Zone Administrator');
        }
      );
    });

    console.log('DONE!')

  }
```

NOTE:  `this.registerFanZoneAdminForm.get('fanZoneAdminArray').value.forEach(element => {..})` is there because I used `FormArray`. Here value is an `Array<FanZoneAdministrators>` and element is single `FanZoneAdministrator`
(Same goes for `registerLocationAdminForm.get('locationAdminArray').value.forEach(element=>{..})`)

Sequence of HTTP requests should be like in the code : Location - > List of Fan Zone Administratos - > List of Location Administrators

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the next request once the response to the current request comes in.

Here is an example:

```
let fanZoneAdminArray = this.registerFanZoneAdminForm.get('fanZoneAdminArray').value;
let locationAdminArray = this.registerLocationAdminForm.get('locationAdminArray').value;

this.locationService.registerLocation(this.location).subscribe((response: Response) => {
    fanZoneAdminRecursion(0, fanZoneAdminArray, () => {
        locationAdminRecursion(0, locationAdminArray, () => {
            // All requests were sent.
        });
    });
  });


let fanZoneAdminRecursion = (index, array, onDone) => {

    let fanZoneAdmin = new User(element.username,element.password,element.email,element.firstName,element.lastName,element.city,element.phoneNumber, null,null,null,null, null,this.location.fanZone,null,new Role("FZA"),null);

    this.usersService.registerFanZoneAdmin(fanZoneAdmin).subscribe((response: Response) => {
      if(index < array.length - 1){
          fanZoneAdminRecursion(++index, array, onDone);
      }else{
         onDone();
      }
   });      
}


let locationAdminRecursion = (index, array, onDone) => {

  let locationAdmin = new User(element.username,element.password,element.email,element.firstName,element.lastName,element.city,element.phoneNumber,  null, null,null, null, null,null,this.location, new Role("LA"),null);

  this.usersService.registerLocationAdmin(locationAdmin).subscribe((response: Response) => {
      if(index < array.length - 1){
          locationAdminRecursion(++index, array, onDone);
      }else{
          onDone();
      }
  });
}
```

Here I'm using recursion to call a function that processes the next element in the array once the response for the previous element comes in.

This can be made a lot less complex using `Promise`. With promises, this will be as easy as `Promise.all(firstCall, secondCall, ....)`.

Comment: `Promise.all` isn't the right method because it allows the concurrency. To serialized them use `await` or `then`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, you're right. I didn't explain it correctly, `Promise.all` should be used instead of the recursive functions, something like: `registerLocation(() => Promise.all(...fanZoneAdminArray).then(() => Promise.all(...locationAdminArray)))`

Comment: yes that makes more sense. However, since the OP is already using a transpiler await would be more readable.  but you would still use all yes

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys! I've fixed the issue based on your solution!